# Query for updating a column in same table from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to update the authorid column which are matching  (where documentculture = 'en-US'

to matching (where documentculture = 'el-GR' in the same table. which includes a inner join to another table

I written like below which looks wrong:

```
  UPDATE t1
  SET t1.authorid = t2.authorid
  FROM wv_blogdata AS t1
  INNER JOIN wv_blogdata AS t2
  ON t1.documentnodeid = t2.documentnodeid
  inner join CMS_Document d
  ON d.BlogDataID = d.DocumentForeignKeyValue
  WHERE t2.DocumentCulture = 'en-US';
```

could you please correct me?

More explanation:

```
select authorid from wv_blogdata 
inner join CMS_Document 
on wv_blogdata.BlogDataID = CMS_Document.DocumentForeignKeyValue
Where DocumentCulture ='el-GR'
```

The author id of above query is different from authorid of below query
which i want to make it synch

```
select authorid from wv_blogdata 
inner join CMS_Document 
on wv_blogdata.BlogDataID = CMS_Document.DocumentForeignKeyValue
Where DocumentCulture ='en-US'
```

Comment: Assuming I understand the data structure, try adding `AND t1. DocumentCulture ='el-GR'` to the where clause on your update statement.

Comment: can  u post complete query?

Comment: If you could edit your question to include sample data as ddl + dml and desired result, I could write a complete, testable query.

Comment: @SmartestVEGA, Please check an answer I just posted. It should work. Let me know if you see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Zohar Peled says in the comments, unless you give sample data, expected results as well as your current DML it's hard to produce an accurate answer to your question.

That being said, in general terms if you can produce a select statement using table aliases that shows both the field to be updated and the field with the new value then you can use it as the basis for a successful UPDATE query.

So if the correct results are shown in this query(your original converted into a SELECT):

```
    SELECT t1.authorid AS OldValue, t2.authorid AS NewValue
      FROM wv_blogdata AS t1
INNER JOIN wv_blogdata AS t2
        ON t1.documentnodeid = t2.documentnodeid
INNER JOIN CMS_Document d
        ON d.BlogDataID = d.DocumentForeignKeyValue
     WHERE t2.DocumentCulture = 'en-US';
```

you will get the correct outcome from this query(your original):

```
    UPDATE t1
       SET t1.authorid = t2.authorid
      FROM wv_blogdata AS t1
INNER JOIN wv_blogdata AS t2
        ON t1.documentnodeid = t2.documentnodeid
INNER JOIN CMS_Document d
        ON d.BlogDataID = d.DocumentForeignKeyValue
     WHERE t2.DocumentCulture = 'en-US';
```

Remembering of course to test your work for unexpected outcomes and hidden gotchas.

Again without sufficient sample data it's really hard to give you a definitive answer, so include as much detail as possible to help us help you.

Hope this helps you to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should make the records in sync so authorid of german blogs and authorid of usa blogs will become the same after you run this query.

Note that `top(1)` is required so only one value is returned by the sub-query else if there are multiple blog records for german culture you will encounter an error.

```
UPDATE b  
SET b.authorid =
  (SELECT top(1) wvb.authorid
   FROM wv_blogdata wvb
   INNER JOIN CMS_Document cms ON wvb.BlogDataID = cms.DocumentForeignKeyValue
   WHERE cms.DocumentCulture ='el-GR' AND b.BlogDataID = cms.DocumentForeignKeyValue order by wvb.authorid)
 FROM wv_blogdata b
  INNER JOIN CMS_Document  ON b.BlogDataID = CMS_Document.DocumentForeignKeyValue
WHERE CMS_Document.DocumentCulture ='en-US';
```

Comment: document culture is in CMS_document table

Comment: The US blog authorid is set to german blog authorid. Isn't that the result you want?

Comment: there are multiple autor id for same culture for different DocumentForeignKeyValue  

so it should match wv_blogdata.BlogDataID = document.DocumentForeignKeyValue

Comment: Then, add an extra condition for this in sub query. I will update it in sometime.